# GitHub repo changed to "other" repo

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo from GitHub Web to my PC with GitHub Win.

all was fine last week and the repo was under "GitHub" repos.

Today I noticed it has moved to "Other" repors

Ho can I associate it back to the GitHub web repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the directory that you cloned the repository to locally there is a .git folder.  Within that folder there will be a config file.  In the config file you should see a `[remote "origin"]` section.  Verify that the value set for url in that section is the correct one for the repository that you cloned. The section should look something like this:

    `[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/bower/bower.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: yeah, there where some complications, but generally this helped me on the right track.